# How to retrieve a button based off an accessibility identifier and a label

Tags: swift, xcuitest, xcuielement

This is the error that's shown, when trying to retrieve an element that has the accessibility identifier `car`, and a label `add`:

`children` comes from:

`let children = elements.descendants(matching: .any)["home"]`

```
No matches found for Descendants matching type Button from input {(
    Button, identifier: 'car', label: 'add',
    Button, identifier: 'car', label: 'minus-grey', Disabled
)}}
```

I've attempted the use of predicates:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "label == %@", "add")
```

And trying to filter by label:

```
children.buttons["add"]
```

How can I interact with this button please?

Comment: I don't think you should have used `children.buttons`. You shouldn't access `children` here. You are *already* at the level of the buttons, the buttons have no further children buttons. That's what the error message is saying. Where does `children` come from? Access the `buttons` of that directly.

Comment: It would also be very helpful if you can show a [mcve].

Comment: Thank you @Sweeper, I've added where `children` comes from as well.

Comment: I thought `children.buttons[]` wouldn't try to access further descendants, but rather just what's within the children array.

Comment: `children.firstMatch.tap()` did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`children.firstMatch.tap()` resolved the issue.